# Regular expression - Set of possible character matches

Tags: python, regex

I need to test a regular expression for a set of possible character matches,

The field 'TEST' can take these possible values - 'TEST1','TEST2','TEST3'...'TEST10'

```
import re
pattern = 'TEST[0123456789]
field = 'TEST1'

match = re.search(match,field)
```

How do I specify the value of [10] in the pattern matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST(?:[1-9]|10)\b
```

This fixes a couple of scenarios that the other answers here did not.

In action: http://www.rubular.com/r/0if2CHfa6l

Answer (score 7):

`10` is a 2-character string:

```
r'TEST\d{1,2}'
```

would match one or two digits; `\d` matches any character in the range from 0 through to 9; it is the shorthand equivalent of `[0123456789]`.

Alternatively, use two alternatives:

```
r'TEST(?:\d|10)'
```

would allow for *1* digit, *or* would allow for `10`. Note that it'll still match `TEST11` because that string **starts** with `TEST1`. Add a boundary test if you want to prevent that to match still:

```
r'TEST(?:\d|10)\b'
```

Demo of that last pattern:

```
>>> re.search(r'TEST(?:\d|10)\b', 'TEST0').group()
'TEST0'
>>> re.search(r'TEST(?:\d|10)\b', 'TEST8').group()
'TEST8'
>>> re.search(r'TEST(?:\d|10)\b', 'TEST10').group()
'TEST10'
>>> re.search(r'TEST(?:\d|10)\b', 'TEST11') is None
True
```